# Ошибка в базе данных JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Есть начальные данные для каждого аккаунта

```
const accounts = require('./base/coins.json');
const pathAccount = './base/coins.json';
    const settings = {
        "balance": 0
    }
```

Потом идёт проверка на новое сообщение через VK Api и если пользователя нету, то он его добавляет.

```
if (!accounts[context.senderId] && context.senderId > 0){
accounts[context.senderId] = settings;
fs.writeFileSync(pathAccount, JSON.stringify(accounts, null, '\t'));
var name = await get_name(context.senderId);
context.send(`
Здравствуй @id`+context.senderId +`(`+name+`), добро пожаловать в интерфейс нашего бота. Регистрация прошла успешна, можно приступать к использованию. Напишите "!команды" чтобы получить список команд и клавиатуру.`)
}
```

Есть единственная команда, которую я выполню

```
updates.hear(/!баланс (\d+) (\d+)/i, async (context) => {
  accounts[context.$match[1]].balance = Number(context.$match[2]);
  fs.writeFileSync(pathAccount, JSON.stringify(accounts, null, '\t'));
});
```

По плану, должно было сохранится значение баланса для одного пользователя, а когда их несколько, получается так, что сохраняется значение сразу для всех пользователей. Почему так я до сих пор не понял.

*Если вкратце для тех кто не шарит в VK API, я сохраняю в одну ячейку памяти JSON значение, и оно сохраняется на все ячейки памяти. Чудо не правда-ли?*

**Примеры**

После выполнения команды "!баланс 1 228", вид базы данных должен быть:

```
"1": {
    "balance": 228
}
"123": {
    "balance": 0
}
"228": {
    "balance": 1
}
```

А не таким

```
"1": {
    "balance": 228
}
"123": {
    "balance": 228
}
"228": {
    "balance": 228
}
```

***Весь мой код***

```
const { VK, Keyboard } = require('vk-io'); 
const randomFloat = require('random-float'); 
const vk = new VK(); 
const accounts = require('./base/coins.json'); 
const pathAccount = './base/coins.json'; 
var fs = require("fs");
const { updates } = vk;

vk.setOptions({
  token: 'токен',
  pollingGroupId: '181482968',
  apiLimit: 20,
  webhookPath: '/webhook/secret-path'
});

const settings = { 
"balance": 0, 
"something": "to be continued" 
} 

updates.use(async (context, next) => { 
if (context.type === 'message' && context.isOutbox) { 
return; 
} 
try { 
await next(); 
} catch (error) { 
console.error('Ошибка:', error); 
} 
if (!accounts[context.senderId]&&context.senderId>0){ 
accounts[context.senderId] = settings; 
fs.writeFileSync(pathAccount, JSON.stringify(accounts, null, '\t')); 
context.send('привет');
} 
})

updates.hear(/!баланс (\d+) (\d+)/i, async (context) => { 
accounts[context.$match[1]].balance = Number(context.$match[2]); 
fs.writeFileSync(pathAccount, JSON.stringify(accounts, null, '\t')); 
context.send('сохрится');
});

vk.updates.startPolling();
console.log('Polling started');
vk.updates.startWebhook();
console.log('Webhook server started');
```

Comment: Вы тут: `accounts[context.senderId] = settings;` присваиваете всем accounts ссылку на один и тот же объект. И изменяя его в одном месте, видите, что он изменился везде. Потому что ссылка.

Comment: можно по подробнее?